# No Invitations ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-classroom, google-admin-settings-api

I have many google classroom invitations and I want to accept all of them through google app script using

```
Classroom.Invitations.accept("courseId");
```

but then I get no data back...

so I tried listing all my invitations using

```
Classroom.Invitations.list({"userId":"my_email"});
```

and  still I get no data back...

I am very sure that my google classroom is full of unaccepted courses

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, an error occurs at `var teacherEmails=(john.doe@gmail.com,jane.doe@gmail.com);`.
- I thought that your script might be for a python script. If you want to use this method using Google Apps Script, it is required to modify it.

When these points are reflected in a Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Classroom API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const courseId = "###"; // Please set your course ID.
  const teacherEmails = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "jane.doe@gmail.com"]; // Please set email addresses.

  teacherEmails.forEach(userId => {
    const res = Classroom.Invitations.create({ courseId, userId, role: "TEACHER" });
    console.log(res)
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: invitations.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/create)

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in Google App Script, you will need to use the **Classroom.Invitations.create()** function in your code and pass the necessary parameters.

```
 function createInvitation() {
  var courseId = '1234567890';
  var userEmail = 'test@google.com';
  var role = 'TEACHER';
  var invitation = {
    userId: userEmail,
    courseId: courseId,
    role: role
  };
  var response = Classroom.Invitations.create(invitation);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```